# Multiple Re-renders for the same item in map() function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, event-handling

I have a state variable called `arrowsArray` that stores an array of objects. While mapping through this array, for the same item it is entering the map multiple times.

```
{arrowsArray.length>=1 && arrowsArray.map((arrow,index) => {
        return(
        <div key={Math.random()}>
          <line
            x1={arrow.startX}
            y1={arrow.startY}
            x2={arrow.endX}
            y2={arrow.endY}
            stroke="black"
            strokeWidth="2"
          ></line>
          <polygon
            // x={endX}
            // y={endY}
            points={`${arrow.endX},${arrow.endY + 5} ${arrow.endX},${arrow.endY - 5} ${
              arrow.endX >= arrow.startX ? arrow.endX + 5 : arrow.endX - 5
            },${arrow.endY}`}
            fill="black"
            stroke="black"
            strokeWidth="2"
          />
        </div>);
      })}
```

I suspect this is due to a `useEffect`. I have two event listeners, as shown below

```
useEffect(() => {
    const handleMouseMove = (event) => {
      setEndX(event.clientX);
      setEndY(y);
    };

    const handleMouseClick = (event) => {
      console.log(dragOnGoing);

      if (!dragOnGoing) {
        dragOnGoing = true;
        setStartX(event.clientX);
        setStartY(event.clientY);
        s_x = event.clientX;
        y = event.clientY;
        document.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
      } else {
        document.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
        // console.log("not dragging");
        setEndX(event.clientX);
        setEndY(y);
        let arrow = arrowsArray;
        arrow.push({
          startX: s_x,
          startY: y,
          endX: event.clientX,
          endY: y,
        });
        setArrowsArray(arrow);
        dragOnGoing = false;

        return;
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener("click", handleMouseClick);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
      document.removeEventListener("click", handleMouseClick);
    };
  }, []);
```

What i'm trying to do in the `useEffect` is to get the value of two coordinates there will be an arrow rendered from the first coordinates  to the second coordinates. First onclick will set the values of `startX`, `startY`; Second onclick will set the values of `endX`, `endY`. now these four coordinates are made into an object and pushed into `arrowsArray`. On checking the state of the `arrowsArray` after every pair of clicks it is as expected, i.e one object is pushed for every pair of  clicks.

Answer (score -1):

You're **mutating** the state by using `push`, you should not mutate state variables. Here's where the problem is:

```js
  let arrow = arrowsArray; 
        arrow.push({
          startX: s_x,
          startY: y,
          endX: event.clientX,
          endY: y,
        });
        setArrowsArray(arrow);
```

Proper way would be to do it like this:

```js
setArrowsArray([...arrowsArray, {
          startX: s_x,
          startY: y,
          endX: event.clientX,
          endY: y,
        }]);
```

You might want to give https://react.dev/learn/updating-arrays-in-state a read on how to handle state with arrays. And how to properly copy an array: https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/35-es6-way-to-clone-an-array/#why-can-t-i-use-to-copy-an-array.  Hope that helps!

Comment: you're right, but that doesn't answer the expected behaviour. I tried and it's still executing the map function on mouse move

Comment: Seems like a misunderstood. **Calling a state setter function any time will cause re-renders automatically**, that's what `useState` setters functions do. And that's happening in your event listeners. If you don't want to trigger re-renders you can use `useRef()` hook instead.